How do I pass hex characters to printf in a script command?
How do I get printf to output hex characters when run from a script?
Suppose I am at the prompt and type  printf "\x41\x42" the output I get
 AB%

However if I have a script containing that line  i.e.   cat test.sh produces
printf "\x41\x42"

But executing the script ./test.sh produces
\x41\x42%

How do I get the script to produce the same results as from the shell prompt?

maybe, this can help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604270/hexadecimal-escapes-to-textutf-8-bash-script

What shell is your interactive shell (zsh?) and what shell is executing your script (dash?)?

Using /usr/bin/printf fixes my issue, but your comment has taught me that the shells could be different. I thought they were the same unless the script specifically said what shell to use. But I'm using zsh but the script is using /bin/sh

Try using the external printf utility:
/usr/bin/printf "\x41\x42"

You have probably have a bash shell but as your interactive shell, while sh is linked to dash.
The dash built-in printf doesn't know \xNN, so  you have to use octal values, \0NN, instead.
The bash built-in printf does know \xNN
